# An error occurred when add trying to add "AdMob"

Tags: firebase, react-native, admob

**Hi, I want to  use  "AdMob" according to the this site
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start
but show some errors can you please help me.**

- What went wrong:

  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-firebase_admob'.

  > Cannot set the value of read-only property 'force' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.android.gms', name='play-services-ads', version='19.8.0', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s

error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
The google-services Gradle plugin needs to be applied on a project with com.android.application or com.android.dynamic-feature. FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures. 1: Task failed with an exception. ----------- * Where: Build file 'G:\20.react native 2023\Filimo\node_modules@react-native-firebase\admob\android\build.gradle' line: 109 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-firebase_admob'. > Cannot set the value of read-only property 'force' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.android.gms', name='play-services-ads', version='19.8.0', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. ============================================================================== 2: Task failed with an exception. ----------- * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase_admob'. > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.o

[image]

[image]
android -> app-> build.gradle
[image]

[image]

Thanks